# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

[Name of Chinese space forces](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/124263/name-of-chinese-space-forces)

I made one of the first comments, and it's almost exactly like what @Thucydides wrote 7 hours later.  It was't rude, bigoted, abusive, unfriendly or unkind, and was certainly "needed".

Comment: As of now, even @Thucydides' comment has been removed. I didn't see your original comment. This seems to be a case where a brief answer was sufficient for the question.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are for asking for clarification or suggesting improvements.

Comments are not for posting answers.

Comments are second-class (or even third-class) citizens on Stack Exchange, and can be deleted at almost any time for almost any reason, with or without diamond moderator involvement.

Just because a later comment hasn't been deleted doesn't make the original deletion inappropriate.

Compare [What are the criteria for comment deletion?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6276/29) and [stackoverflow comment etiquette](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4805/29) and [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/157730) (for the latter, particularly the sections on *Who can delete comments?* and *When should comments be deleted?*)

Comment: Some answers only need to be one or two sentences, yet they are quickly flagged VLQ.  Unnecessary fluff has to be added to make the moderators happy.

Comment: @RonJohn I am not sure how this comment is relevant to the discussion, can you elaborate?

Comment: @James it's justification for why I (and L Dutch, who answered this question with a comment, and who was then called on it) answered the question in a comment.

Comment: @James interestingly, someone deleted **all** the comments on my question, wiping away history as if it had never happened.  Very sad.

Comment: @RonJohn Suppose someone did delete only the initial comment on your question here, a comment which was an answer disguised as a comment. Now the three follow-up comments would have referred to a nonexistent comment. I didn't delete the comments, but I'd personally find that situation worse, not better, than all of them having been deleted.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The only thing I would add to this post is that comments are intended to be ephemeral. So there is that.

Comment: @RonJohn "*Some answers only need to be one or two sentences, yet they are quickly flagged VLQ.*" then address that instead. [Short answers don't always mean VLQ as long as it answers the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161095/do-one-line-of-code-answers-count-as-vlq). Or, well... since the question is closed, then it's better not to provide any answer *at all* (even in the comment) since it just give negative feedback to the asker that they will get the answer even for off-topic questions...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not *certain* but I'm pretty sure I flagged the comment in question as being too much of answer to be left as a comment, or in fact to be left as a one liner. It was good material that deserved proper elaboration. My opinion was subsequently upheld at moderation.